# Round Button and Flexible Margin in Layout in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am wondering, what is the best approach to achieve this kind of layout?

[image]

I have been trying various approaches, but my button keeps sticking to each other. and I have no idea to create a layout in XML that totally respect all screen sizes.

Any ideas please?

Comment: try creating shapes for circle

Comment: Use `weight` in `LinearLayout`, it will do some of your work easier.

Comment: Thats not the problem, but rather I would like a flexible way of arranging that kind of layout so it will be displayed perfectly on all devices. the circle part does not concern me. thanks for commenting @VivekMishra

Comment: use a gridView for keypad

Comment: what you have tried yet?????

Comment: then you either use gridview or weights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i thought to give you some hint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/numericPad"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/statusMessage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25sp" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25sp" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="6dip"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25sp" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is how I created this layout but this was in landscape mode and this is for only one row

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Linearlayout with weightsum as well as circle shapes. That will be perfect in all mobile screens. Like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout        
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="3" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="4" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="5" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="6" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="7" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="8" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="9" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

back.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```